# How to Create SLD Label with Non-Latin Languages

Tags: openlayers-2, wms

I create a OpenLayers WMS Layer  with my map server url. 
I want to Style this with SLD_Body. I defined My SLD_Body and want to labeling it.

but My Label Map is with non-Latin language and after executing the program , the labels is shown with Question mark(????).

Is there any way to display labels in My language??

this is my code:

```
        var wmsm = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("wms", mapurl,
      {
          layers: Mylayers,
          format: 'image/png',
          "SLD_BODY": sld },
          {"reproject":"true"}                    
        );
```

Comment: does it work with a SLD file installed on the server? does the server have the font installed?

Comment: Along with @iant but slightly different...  If the server has the font and it works locally, it might not work to other clients if they don't have the font.  I am assuming that it is the clients who render the label, not the server.  If that is the case, you would need to embed the font into the webpage via CSS (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp) for the client to have access to.

Comment: @Branco - this is a WMS so it is rendered on the server.

Comment: @iant.  Makes sense.  I wasn't 100% sure if labels were rendered there too or if it did something weird like create individually positioned DIVs on the client.  Now that I type it out, it sounds pretty stupid though.